# I want to output * as a number and repeat the output as many times as I have entered

Tags: c

I got a problem of completing the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void triR(void) 
{
    int size, repeat;
    scanf("%d %d", &size, &repeat);
    printf("Hello world\n");

    // ...
    // Complete this function
    // ...

    printf("Bye world\n");
}
```

[Example of function excution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poSAN.png)

The above three are the input values.

I think The first is the minimum size of the number (I do not know why it does not work if I do not enter 1), the middle is the maximum size of the number, and the last is the number of iterations of the input value.

After looking at the example, I created the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

void triR(void)     
{    
   int size, repeat;    
   int num;    
      scanf("%d %d", &size, &repeat);    
      printf("Hello world\n");            
     for (int b = 0; b < size; ++b) //b = horizontal line, a = number    
     {    
         for (int a = 0; a <= b; ++a)    
        {    
            for (num = 1; num <= a; ++num)     - failed sentences
               {    
                   printf("%d", num);    
               }    
         }    
         printf("\n");    
     }              
    for (int k = size; k > 0 ; --k) //k = horizontal line, i = number     
    {    
        for (int i = 1; i < k; ++i)    
        {    
               {    
                   printf("*");     -Sentences that were successfully run using *
                }    
         }    
             printf("n");    
    }    
    // for (int c =o; )           - sentences tried to make about repeating output value

    printf("Bye world\n");    
    return 0;    
}
```

I know my code looks a lot strange.
I didn't have the confidence to make that code in numbers, so I tried to make it * and convert it.
It succeeded in running by *, but it continues to fail in the part to execute by number.

There is no one to ask for help, but I am afraid that I will not be able to solve it even if I am alone in the weekend. I can not even convert numbers far repeated outputs. I would really appreciate it even if you could give me a hint.

[The above code I created(Failed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ6d8.jpg)

[Code with *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z4k5.jpg)

Comment: The images you've linked are just text, and it would be nice if you could copy and paste the userful bits of their content directly into your question.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to say that even though I managed an implementation, it is definitely neither efficient nor practical. I had to restrict your size variable to digits, as I used ASCII to convert the numbers into characters and couldn't use the itoa() function, since it's not standard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void triR(void) {
    int size, repeat;
    scanf("%d %d", &size,&repeat);
    printf("Hello world\n");

    // string size of n^2+2n-1
    char* print_string = malloc((size*size+2*size-1)*sizeof(char));
    unsigned int number = 1;
    unsigned int incrementer = 1;
    while (number < size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            *(print_string+i+incrementer-1) = 48+number;
        }
        incrementer+=number;
        number++;
        *(print_string+incrementer-1) = '\n';
        incrementer++;

    }
    while (number > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            *(print_string+i+incrementer-1) = 48+number;
        }
        incrementer+=number;
        number--;
        *(print_string+incrementer-1) = '\n';
        incrementer++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", print_string);
    }

    printf("Bye world\n");
    free(print_string);
}
```

I allocated a char* with the size of size^2+2size-1, as this is the size required for the newline and number characters.

The variables number and incrementer are unsigned and start at 1 as they don't need to go below 1.

I put two while loops with similar code blocks in them:

```
    while (number < size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            *(print_string+i+incrementer-1) = 48+number;
        }
        incrementer+=number;
        number++;
        *(print_string+incrementer-1) = '\n';
        incrementer++;

    }
    while (number > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            *(print_string+i+incrementer-1) = 48+number;
        }
        incrementer+=number;
        number--;
        *(print_string+incrementer-1) = '\n';
        incrementer++;
    }
```

The first loop goes up to the size and inserts the characters into the char* in their positions. When the number is done, it increments the incrementer and adds the newline character.

The second loop goes down in number, doing the same things but this time decrementing the number variable. These two variables start at 1, as that's the start of the "pyramid".

```
*(print_string+i+incrementer-1) = 48+number;
```

There is a restriction here, in that if you exceed the number 9 your output will print whatever the ASCII representation of 58 is, so if you want to go above 9, you need to change that.

The for loop just prints the final string "repeat" times as wanted. The newline in the printf() function is not necessary, as the final string contains a newline character at the end, I left it in though. The downside of this implementation is that you're using a char* rather than some other sophisticated method.

Dont forget to free the char* when you're done, and don't forget to add user input error-checking.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

void clear(FILE *stream)
{
    int ch;  // read characters from stream till EOF or a newline is reached:
    while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int min, max, count;
    while (scanf("%d %d %d", &min, &max, &count) != 3 ||  // repeat till all 3 fields read successfully and
        !min || !max || !count || min > max) { // only accept positive numbers as input
        fputs("Input error!\n\n", stderr);     // and make sure that the max is greater than the min
        clear(stdin);  // remove everything from stdin before attempting another read for values
    }

    puts("Hello world\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {  // output the triangle count times

        for (int row = min; row <= max; ++row) {  // count row from min to max
            for (int n = min; n <= row; ++n)  // print row (row-min) times
                printf("%d ", row);
            putchar('\n');  // add a newline after every row
        }

        for (int row = max - 1; row >= min; --row) {  // count from max-1 to min
            for (int n = min; n <= row; ++n)  // same as above: print row (row-min) times
                printf("%d ", row);
            putchar('\n');  // add a newline after every row
        }

        putchar('\n');  // add a newline between repetitions
    }

    puts("Bye world\n");
}
```